# Ubuntu gets black screen after initial logo

Tags: 16.04, systemd

Tonight I was using my Ubuntu and after I finished all my work, I turned it off. Today, I'm trying to boot it, but I'm getting a black screen right after the Ubuntu Logo.

After a long time searching for answers, I used the advanced option to start Ubuntu with systemd. I'm still having a black screen after my boot, but when I set to start it with systemd, it works.

Does anybody knows why?

I'm using UBUNTU 16.04 LTS

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "set to to start with systemd" ? Ubuntu 16.04 normally boots with systemd. What commands or keystrokes are using in the case that fails and the case that succeeds?